# How to display the output of a file on one line with commas?

Tags: java, file

Code is here:

https://pastebin.com/08KBcnUX

Here is my current output:

**OUTPUT:**

```
Integer Array Contents: 
, -3, 2, 0, 0, 1, -5
Total odd numbers: 3
Odd numbers are: -3 1 -5 0 0 0 
Index of last zero: 3
Minimum: -5
Maximum: 2
Sum: -5
Element mean is: 0.0
//1) How do I get rid of the random "," at the beginning? Lol 
//2) How do I get rid of the 0's that are in the "Odd numbers are: " category. 
//3) Mean's not working. What should I do to fix that. Maybe it has something to do     
//with the extra zeroes? I made it into a double and that didnt do anything either.
```

Comment: your code please...

Comment: In the Pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.out.print` instead with a comma like this:

```
int trues = 0;
int falses = 0;
int firstindex = -1;//first index init with -1 to check with it later
String del = "";
int i = 0;
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scan.next();
    if (line.equals("true")) {//if the line equal true then trues++;
        if (firstindex == -1) {//if the first index == -1 then assign 
                               //it to i number of words
            firstindex = i;
        }
        trues++;
    } else if (line.equals("false")) {//if the line equal false falses++
        falses++;
    }
    System.out.print(del + line);
    del = ",";
    i++;
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Total TRUEs: " + trues);
System.out.println("Total TRUEs: " + falses);
System.out.println("Index of first TRUE: " + 
                      (firstindex > -1 ? firstindex : "No true in file"));
```

`(firstindex > -1 ? firstindex : "No true in file")` mean if the input == -1 print **No true in file** else print the index

**Output**

```
Welcome to the Info-Array Program!
Please enter the filename for the Boolean values: Boolean Array Contents: 
true,true,false,true,false,true
Total TRUEs: 4
Total TRUEs: 2
Index of first TRUE: 0
```

Comment: Thats good! How would I go about getting to my more ideal output of counting the total number of TRUEs and FALSEs and then the index of the first?

Comment: **This is really bad action to down-vote why it is down-vote, where i'm wrong?**

Comment: no idea, I didn't down vote. Yours is the best help so far. @YCF_L

Comment: thank you @Ousmane Mahy Diaw i really don't know why people down-vote without any reason

Comment: @YCF_L your answer is correct and considering OP has even stated _Yours is the best help so far._ I don't see the reason for a downvote, but I guess you'll have to accept it and move on. ^^

Comment: I appreciate it @YCF_L i didnt downvote. It doesn't even count because my reputation is below 15 so even if I did down vote it wouldnt be shown. Theres a second half to this that I'm gonna need some help on so stand by :) Thanks again!

Comment: no no i know you are not you @way245 don't worry good luck :)

Comment: @YCF_L I am going to post a pastebin of what I'm working on now so I don't crowd up everything

Comment: @way245 if you want to solve another problem you have to create another question, just make your question clean ok

Comment: @YCF_L it wont let me ask a question

Comment: thats why I was just going to link pastebin with everything clean and the info I need. Is that okay?

Comment: @YCF_L wouldnt let me post so I had to edit everything. Hoping you can help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to accomplish this would be to utilize `Files#readAllLines` which reads every line of a `File` into a `List<Stirng>`.  Then, you can use `String#join` to easily combine every `String` with a comma as a delimiter.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());

String fileContents = String.join(",", lines);
```

If you want to return the total number of `true` elements, simply `Stream` the `List<String>` and filter out the elements that are equal to `true`, and finally use `Stream#count` to get the amount:

```
long numTrueElements = lines.stream().filter(s -> s.equals("true")).count();
```

If you want to return the total number of `false` elements, simply subtract the total number of `true` elements from the size of the `List<Stirng>` of lines.

```
int numFalseElements = lines.size() - numTrueElements;
```

If you want the index of the first `true` element, then you can use `List#indexOf`:

```
int firstTrueIndex = lines.indexOf("true");
```

With this method, you can ditch the `Scanner` and any loop entirely.

Comment: This a nice answer using java 8 you just need to change `int` to `long` like this `long numTrueElements = lines.stream().filter(s -> s.equals("true")).count();
            long numFalseElements = lines.size() - numTrueElements;` because `count()` return `long` and not `int` **(+1)**

Comment: @YCF_L Thank you, I had it backwards.

Comment: @JacobG. if you don't change it, the code won't compile. plus there is **no** automatic **downcast**. **widening** is automatic **narrowing** is explicit.

Answer (score 0):

```
String line=null;
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            line += scan.nextLine()+",";
        }
        System.out.println("Boolean Array Contents: "+line);
int count = line.split(",").length;
```